# how can I draw a circle and a line at the same time in an interface?

Tags: c++, qt

I managed to draw a line and a circle by the two functions mousepress event and paintevent.
I want ideas like when I activate a button in the toolbar I will activate the function that draws the line and if I click on another button I activate the function that draws the circle.

```
 void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
    {
      if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        (firstClick ? start : end) = pQEvent->pos();

        if(firstClick = !firstClick)
        {
            double distance=sqrt(pow(start.x()-end.x(), 2) + pow(start.y()-end.y(), 2));
            emit  sendCalculDistance(distance);
        }
        update();
        pQEvent->accept();

      }


    }
    void Label::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent)
    {
      QLabel::paintEvent(pQEvent);
      if (!firstClick) return;
      QPainter painter(this);
      QPen pen(Qt::red);
      pen.setWidth(4);
      painter.setPen(pen);
      painter.drawLine(start, end);
    }
    ****************
   /* void Label::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
    {
      if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
        (firstClick ? center : mouse_pos) = pQEvent->pos();

        firstClick = !firstClick;

        update();
        pQEvent->accept();

      }
    }
    void Label::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent)
    {
      QLabel::paintEvent(pQEvent);
      if (!firstClick) return;
      int radius = QLineF( center, mouse_pos ).length();
        QPainter painter( this );
        QPen pen(Qt::red);
        pen.setWidth(4);
        painter.setPen(pen);
        painter.drawEllipse( center, radius, radius );
    }
*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is somehow a continuation of my answer to [SO: update does not call paintEvent?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56481566/7478597).

Hence, I took the previous sample code (still laying around on my HDD) and made the respective extensions:

1. a mode to differentiate the drawing primitive:

```
enum PaintMode {
  PaintLine, PaintCirc, NPaintModes
};
```

2. a new member variable to remember the current drawing primitive (in `class MainWindow`):

```
    PaintMode _paintMode;
```

3. an extension to the `MainWindow::paintEvent()`:

```
  switch (_paintMode) {
    case PaintLine:
      painter.drawLine(_start, _end);
      break;
    case PaintCirc: {
      const int width = std::abs(_end.x() - _start.x());
      const int height = std::abs(_end.y() - _start.y());
      const int r = std::min(width, height) / 2;
      painter.drawEllipse((_start + _end) / 2, r, r);
    } break;
  }
```

4. a toolbar to select current drawing primitive:

```
  QToolBar qToolBar;
  QActionGroup qTglGrp(&qToolBar);
  QAction qTglLine("Line", &qTglGrp);
  qTglLine.setCheckable(true);
  if (winMain.paintMode() == PaintLine) qTglLine.setChecked(true);
  qToolBar.addAction(&qTglLine);
  QAction qTglCirc("Circle", &qTglGrp);
  qTglCirc.setCheckable(true);
  if (winMain.paintMode() == PaintCirc) qTglCirc.setChecked(true);
  qToolBar.addAction(&qTglCirc);
  winMain.addToolBar(&qToolBar);
```

5. ... with sufficient signal handlers:

```
  QObject::connect(&qTglLine, &QAction::triggered,
    [&](bool checked) { if (checked) winMain.setPaintMode(PaintLine); });
  QObject::connect(&qTglCirc, &QAction::triggered,
    [&](bool checked) { if (checked) winMain.setPaintMode(PaintCirc); });
```

The complete sample `testQMainWindowPaint.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

enum PaintMode {
  PaintLine, PaintCirc, NPaintModes
};

class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {

  private:
    QPoint _start, _end;
    bool _firstClick;
    PaintMode _paintMode;

  public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow() = default;
    MainWindow(const MainWindow&) = delete;
    MainWindow& operator=(const MainWindow&) = delete;

    PaintMode paintMode() const { return _paintMode; }
    void setPaintMode(PaintMode mode);

  protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override;
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow():
  QMainWindow(),
  _start(0, 0), _end(0, 0), _firstClick(true),
  _paintMode(PaintLine)
{ }

void MainWindow::setPaintMode(PaintMode mode)
{
  _paintMode = mode;
  update();
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    (_firstClick ? _start : _end) = pQEvent->pos();
    _firstClick = !_firstClick;
    update();
    pQEvent->accept();
  }
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent)
{
  QMainWindow::paintEvent(pQEvent);
  if (!_firstClick) return;
  QPainter painter(this);
  QPen pen(Qt::red);
  pen.setWidth(4);
  painter.setPen(pen);
  switch (_paintMode) {
    case PaintLine:
      painter.drawLine(_start, _end);
      break;
    case PaintCirc: {
      const int width = std::abs(_end.x() - _start.x());
      const int height = std::abs(_end.y() - _start.y());
      const int r = std::min(width, height) / 2;
      painter.drawEllipse((_start + _end) / 2, r, r);
    } break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // init GUI
  MainWindow winMain;
  QToolBar qToolBar;
  QActionGroup qTglGrp(&qToolBar);
  QAction qTglLine("Line", &qTglGrp);
  qTglLine.setCheckable(true);
  if (winMain.paintMode() == PaintLine) qTglLine.setChecked(true);
  qToolBar.addAction(&qTglLine);
  QAction qTglCirc("Circle", &qTglGrp);
  qTglCirc.setCheckable(true);
  if (winMain.paintMode() == PaintCirc) qTglCirc.setChecked(true);
  qToolBar.addAction(&qTglCirc);
  winMain.addToolBar(&qToolBar);
  winMain.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTglLine, &QAction::triggered,
    [&](bool checked) { if (checked) winMain.setPaintMode(PaintLine); });
  QObject::connect(&qTglCirc, &QAction::triggered,
    [&](bool checked) { if (checked) winMain.setPaintMode(PaintCirc); });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

The Qt project file (didn't change) `testQMainWindowPaint.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQMainWindowPaint.cc

QT += widgets
```

Compiled in [cygwin64](http://www.cygwin.org) on Windows 10:

```
$ qmake-qt5 testQMainWindowPaint.pro

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQMainWindowPaint.o testQMainWindowPaint.cc
g++  -o testQMainWindowPaint.exe testQMainWindowPaint.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQMainWindowPaint 
Qt Version: 5.9.4
```

After clicking twice into main window, I made a snapshot (left image), and after clicking on <kbd>Circle</kbd> another (right image):

[image: Snapshot of testQMainWindowPaint] [image: Snapshot of testQMainWindowPaint (after clicking [Circle])]

---

IMHO, the application does now what OP required literally:

> I want ideas like when I activate a button in the toolbar I will activate the function that draws the line and if I click on another button I activate the function that draws the circle.

However, I somehow have the feeling that this might not yet be the expected. The painted drawing primitive changes immediately when the paint mode is changed (by clicking in toolbar). Instead, it might be intended that the toolbar choice takes effect for the next input.

If that's the case, the `class MainWindow` has to be changed a bit: There is a second paint mode needed for actual painting which isn't changed before the next interaction cycle is finished:

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow {

  private:
    QPoint _start, _end;
    bool _firstClick;
    PaintMode _paintMode, _paintModeEff;

  public:
    MainWindow();
    virtual ~MainWindow() = default;
    MainWindow(const MainWindow&) = delete;
    MainWindow& operator=(const MainWindow&) = delete;

    PaintMode paintMode() const { return _paintMode; }
    void setPaintMode(PaintMode mode);
    PaintMode effectivePaintMode() const { return _paintModeEff; }

  protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override;
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow():
  QMainWindow(),
  _start(0, 0), _end(0, 0), _firstClick(true),
  _paintMode(PaintLine), _paintModeEff(PaintLine)
{ }

void MainWindow::setPaintMode(PaintMode mode)
{
  _paintMode = mode;
}

void MainWindow::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    (_firstClick ? _start : _end) = pQEvent->pos();
    _firstClick = !_firstClick;
    if (_firstClick) _paintModeEff = _paintMode;
    update();
    pQEvent->accept();
  }
}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent)
{
  QMainWindow::paintEvent(pQEvent);
  if (!_firstClick) return;
  QPainter painter(this);
  QPen pen(Qt::red);
  pen.setWidth(4);
  painter.setPen(pen);
  switch (_paintModeEff) {
    case PaintLine:
      painter.drawLine(_start, _end);
      break;
    case PaintCirc: {
      const int width = std::abs(_end.x() - _start.x());
      const int height = std::abs(_end.y() - _start.y());
      const int r = std::min(width, height) / 2;
      painter.drawEllipse((_start + _end) / 2, r, r);
    } break;
  }
}
```

A line appears after clicking twice (left image), changing paint mode hasn't immediate effect (middle image), but becomes effective when clicking twice again (right image):

[image: Snapshot of testQMainWindowPaint] [image: Snapshot of testQMainWindowPaint (after clicking [Circle])] [image: Snapshot of testQMainWindowPaint (after next input cycle)]

---

Another modification of sample:

The mouse interaction and drawing is now in a `class Canvas` derived from `QWidget`. While the main window is now an instance of `QMainWindow`, there is a new instance `Canvas canvas` which is used as central widget of `QMainWindow winMain`.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

enum PaintMode {
  PaintLine, PaintCirc, NPaintModes
};

class Canvas: public QWidget {

  private:
    QPoint _start, _end;
    bool _firstClick;
    PaintMode _paintMode, _paintModeEff;

  public:
    Canvas();
    virtual ~Canvas() = default;
    Canvas(const Canvas&) = delete;
    Canvas& operator=(const Canvas&) = delete;

    PaintMode paintMode() const { return _paintMode; }
    void setPaintMode(PaintMode mode);
    PaintMode effectivePaintMode() const { return _paintModeEff; }

  protected:
    virtual void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent) override;
    virtual void paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent) override;
};

Canvas::Canvas():
  QWidget(),
  _start(0, 0), _end(0, 0), _firstClick(true),
  _paintMode(PaintLine), _paintModeEff(PaintLine)
{ }

void Canvas::setPaintMode(PaintMode mode)
{
  _paintMode = mode;
}

void Canvas::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *pQEvent)
{
  if (pQEvent->button() == Qt::LeftButton) {
    (_firstClick ? _start : _end) = pQEvent->pos();
    _firstClick = !_firstClick;
    if (_firstClick) _paintModeEff = _paintMode;
    update();
    pQEvent->accept();
  }
}

void Canvas::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *pQEvent)
{
  QWidget::paintEvent(pQEvent);
  if (!_firstClick) return;
  QPainter painter(this);
  QPen pen(Qt::red);
  pen.setWidth(4);
  painter.setPen(pen);
  switch (_paintModeEff) {
    case PaintLine:
      painter.drawLine(_start, _end);
      break;
    case PaintCirc: {
      const int width = std::abs(_end.x() - _start.x());
      const int height = std::abs(_end.y() - _start.y());
      const int r = std::min(width, height) / 2;
      painter.drawEllipse((_start + _end) / 2, r, r);
    } break;
  }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  qDebug() << "Qt Version:" << QT_VERSION_STR;
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  // init GUI
  QMainWindow winMain;
  Canvas canvas;
  winMain.setCentralWidget(&canvas);
  QToolBar qToolBar;
  QActionGroup qTglGrp(&qToolBar);
  QAction qTglLine("Line", &qTglGrp);
  qTglLine.setCheckable(true);
  if (canvas.paintMode() == PaintLine) qTglLine.setChecked(true);
  qToolBar.addAction(&qTglLine);
  QAction qTglCirc("Circle", &qTglGrp);
  qTglCirc.setCheckable(true);
  if (canvas.paintMode() == PaintCirc) qTglCirc.setChecked(true);
  qToolBar.addAction(&qTglCirc);
  winMain.addToolBar(&qToolBar);
  winMain.show();
  // install signal handlers
  QObject::connect(&qTglLine, &QAction::triggered,
    [&](bool checked) { if (checked) canvas.setPaintMode(PaintLine); });
  QObject::connect(&qTglCirc, &QAction::triggered,
    [&](bool checked) { if (checked) canvas.setPaintMode(PaintCirc); });
  // runtime loop
  return app.exec();
}
```

A snapshot of the sample:

[image: Snapshot of testQMainWindowPaint (after clicking twice into canvas)]

Comment: thank you for your detailed explanation I tested it and it works.

Comment: I subclass qlabel to do the processing only over  label of the image so I have main.cpp Label.cpp and mainWindow.cpp
how i can integrate your code in this new situation knowing that i started work with qtdesigner for (actionouvrir and actionquitter.)

Comment: @jas The same code can be applied to a derived `QLabel`. I could have done it deriving `MainWindow` from a simple `QWidget` (with the only exception of `QMainWindow::addToolBar()`). I don't have any experience with Qt Designer. I've never heard about _actionouvrir and actionquitter_ - sorry.

Comment: thank you for your quick answer i will test it,really u help me a lot..

Comment: @Sheff Please,I have already drawn the line and the circle and I calculate the distance and the surface now I want to draw the line and the circle dynamically as in the application of paint.

Comment: @jas The Qt doc. provides a nice and IMHO suitable example: [Scribble Example](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-widgets-scribble-example.html). There are a lot more [Painting Examples](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/examples-painting.html). Have you already checked them out?

Comment: thank you for your answer, I want to calculate the area by the number of pixels is there a function in qt that allows to calculate the number of pixels for dynamic geometric shapes